Motions for selecting code statements?
Let's say I have a line of lua like this:
vim.keymap.set("n", "<D-BS>", function() vim.cmd(":!trash '%'") vim.cmd("bprev|bd#") end)

How could I select the whole statement:
vim.cmd(":!trash '%'")

with my cursor anywhere inside it?
Both around the parentheses and the vim.cmd part?
Would this require some sort of awareness of the language?
Is this something an LSP would handle?

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Without a plugin: no.
Rather than trying to come up with a nifty piece of custom Vimscript (or Lua, it doesn't matter) for every edge case, you can leverage the basic functionality of the editor to do what you want.
Vim is a text editor and does not care about "functions" or "code".
There are some text objects that are recognized by Vim and they are found in :help text-objects.
These are characters that tend to appear in pairs, like quotes or parentheses.
While it's possible to add new text objects, the defaults work reasonably well.
The requirement "with my cursor anywhere inside it" is a bit surprising.
Surely you know where your cursor is?
The cursor is your precision tool.
Doctors don't start to perform heart surgery "with the knife anywhere inside the patient's body".
Depending where your cursor is, there are no more than two steps needed to Visual select the statement.
vim.keymap.set("n", "<D-BS>", function() vim.cmd(":!trash '%'") vim.cmd("bprev|bd#") end)
cursor pos:                              ^
you type: vf)
vim.keymap.set("n", "<D-BS>", function() vim.cmd(":!trash '%'") vim.cmd("bprev|bd#") end)
cursor pos:                               ^..............^
you type: Bvf)
vim.keymap.set("n", "<D-BS>", function() vim.cmd(":!trash '%'") vim.cmd("bprev|bd#") end)
cursor pos:                                     ^.............^
you type: va)oB

And there are several more alternatives.
E.g. you can also search backwards to the previous vim with ?vim<CR> but this is a bit more to type.

I like v% for the first example

@D.BenKnoble I like it, very concise. I remember thinking about it when I wrote this answer ... no idea why I dropped it.

I believe in this case f)v%B works wherever the cursor is in the statements these statement that contains only one pair of parenthesis

An approximation for a function call would be:
f)v%B

Where:

f) selects the list of arguments
v starts the selection
% moves to matching parenthesis
B extends the selection up to the preceding space

